# "one set of something" definite article or not?

Tags: articles

I run into a sentence below:

"It's a short rectangle with a fireplace facing one upon entering, flanked by one set of windows with high radiators beneath and another set of french doors leading to another room"

Why there is not a definite article "the" before windows in *one set of windows.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use "the" in a similar phrase when there are specific items that the set is chosen from. For example a museum might have a collection of windows from various periods and museum workers might refer to a display using some of them as "a set of the windows". Generally though there is nothing so specific about the windows in a set and so they are referred to merely as "a set of windows".